# Pegar valores JS para PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho este código. No entanto está em **JS** e gostaria de jogar os valores para uma var em **PHP** e trabalhar melhor com o Front-End.

```js
<script language="javascript">
var LIP_LowPrecision = false; //false = pede permissao pelo navegador, Maior Precisao | true = nao pede permissao, Menor Precisao
function LocalizaIP_done(ip_data){
  if (!ip_data['error']) //esta linha eh um exemplo, deve trocá-la pelo programa que irá manipular os dados de Geolocalizacao
    alert('Localizei IP: '+ip_data['city']+'-'+ip_data['state']+'-'+ip_data['country']+' (lat:'+ip_data['latitude']+',long:'+ip_data['longitude']+')');
}</script>
```

Como faço isso? Ex.

```
$cidade = +ip_data['city']+;
```

> http://www.localizaip.com.br/api_localiza_ip.php

Comment: @DanielOmine não achei resposta para isso no link acima!

Comment: Preciso pegar esses valores porque do jeito que esta, está me mostrando um alert com os dados, eu apenas quero mostrar em uma variavel sendo assim posso manipular esses dados de quiasquer formas!

Comment: @DanielOmine Entendi, não existe um método mais simples apenas para guardar os valores em uma var?!

Comment: De onde vem `ip_data` e como é invocado `LocalizaIP_done()` ?

Comment: @DanielOmine é uma API que gera um script apenas, não sei dizer :/

Comment: @DanielOmine veja o link da API para melhor intender

Answer (score 0):

O código javascript deve estar dentro do arquivo .php. Certifique-se de manter este código fora da tag do php (  )

Ai, tente fazer o seguinte dentro do código javascript:

```
var cidade = <?php print ip_data['city'] ?>;
```

Answer (score -1):

Como o php está no **servidor** você precisa passar as variáveis por *query string* ou *post*.

Para isso você deve fazer uma *requisição HTTP via URL ou AJAX*, para facilitar use **jQuery**.

```
const postData = {};
postData.city = ...
...
$.post("caminho-do-arquivo.php", postData);
```

ou

```
const a, b, c;
window.location.href = "arquivo.php?a=" + a + "&b=" + b ...
```

Receba no PHP com `$_POST`, `$_GET` ou `$_REQUEST`.

Mas se a questão é facilitar o *front-end*, você pode usar algum *template engine*, exemplo *twig*.